# Make ReactDOM.createPortal insert element as first child of target container (instead of last child)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

So I'm using `ReactDOM.createPortal` to render an element outside it's normal DOM placement. I have to do it since I'm interacting with a library that creates it's own elements (outside my scope) and I have to place one of my DOM elements inside theirs.

What I'm getting using `createPortal` is:

```
<div class="target">
    <div />
    <div class="myDiv" />
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div class="target">
    <div class="myDiv" />
    <div/>
</div>
```

I cannot seem to find how to change the behaviour of `createPortal` make it insert the node as first child.

Comment: A relevant code that you used would be great in order to help

Answer (score 9):

React will use `appendChild` to render a portal, this behaviour is intrinsic and not subject to change.

If a portal should be shown before other children, a container should be provided in existing DOM:

```
<div class="target">
    <div class="portal-container">...rendered portal...</div>
    <div />
</div>
```

If this isn't possible, DOM should be accessed directly to prepend a container programmatically, similarly to [this guide example](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#event-bubbling-through-portals):

```
class PrependedPortal extends React.Component {
  portalRoot = document.querySelector('.target');
  portalContainer = document.createElement('div');

  componentDidMount() {
    this.portalRoot.prepend(this.portalContainer);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.portalRoot.removeChild(this.portalContainer);
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      this.props.children,
      this.portalContainer
    );
  }
}
```

[`prepend` isn't well-supported and needs to be polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) or replaced with similar DOM manipulations, e.g. jQuery `prepend`.

Comment: you can use this function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp and insertBefore the first child of the container

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation using high-order component, hooks, and typescript to do a prepend portal.

```
import { ReactNode, ReactPortal, useEffect } from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'

export const withPrependPortal = (component: ReactNode, container: Element): ReactPortal => {
  const portalContainer = document.createElement('div')

  useEffect(() => {
    container.prepend(portalContainer)
    return () => {
      container.removeChild(portalContainer)
    }
  }, [container, portalContainer])

  return createPortal(
    component,
    portalContainer
  )
}
```

How to use it:

```
const MyPortalComponent = (): ReactPortal =>
        withPrependPortal(<div>Hi prepend portal</div>, document.querySelector(".myContainer") as Element)
```